# php category, sub category tree

Tags: php, mysql

I've done this before in long complicated statements but I'm trying to clean up some code.

I have the following table structures

```
parent_categories            child_categories
-------------------          ----------------------
|pid|category_name|          |ID|category_name|lpid|
| 01| Parent cat 1|          |01|subcategory 1| 01 |
| 02| Parent cat 2|          |02|subcategory 2| 01 |
-------------------          |03|subcategory 3| 02 |
                             ----------------------
```

I am trying to echo the sql results so they would be in this format:

```
Parent Cat 1
    subcategory 1
    subcategory 2
Parent cat 2
    subcategory 3
```

Here is the code I've working with, but its giving way to many results, I get pretty messed up with loops still.

```
$get_categories = "SELECT * FROM
                                parent_categories a
                            INNER JOIN
                                child_categories b
                                ON a.pid = b.lpid";

$q_get= $conn->prepare($get_categories);
$q_get->execute();
    while ($rowCategories= $q_get->fetch())
    {
        echo $rowCategories['parent_name']."<br/>";
            foreach ($rowCategories as $parent)
                {
                    echo $parent."<Br?>";
                    echo $rowCategories['category_name']. "<Br/>";
                }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What you want in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qry = $conn->prepare('
  SELECT   a.pid, a.parent_name, b.category_name
  FROM     parent_categories a
      JOIN child_categories  b ON a.pid = b.lpid
  ORDER BY a.pid
');

if ($qry->execute()) {
  echo '<ul>';

  $row = $qry->fetch();
  while ($row) {
    $current_pid = $row['pid'];

    echo '<li>', htmlentities($row['parent_name']), '<ul>';
    do {
      echo '<li>', htmlentities($row['category_name']), '</li>';
    } while ($row = $qry->fetch() and $row['pid'] == $current_pid);
    echo '</ul></li>';
  }

  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of INNER JOIN is:

```
Parent Cat 1 subcategory 1
Parent Cat 1 subcategory 2
Parent Cat 2 subcategory 3
```

If you want format them as array in array use php

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your loop and foreach loop is of no use, just play with if else to check for the parent is same or different ,the result of query  will have the name of parent category in each row ,

```
$get_categories = "SELECT * 
 FROM parent_categories a
  INNER JOIN  child_categories b ON a.pid = b.lpid
 ORDER BY a.pid";

$currentParent = false;
while ($rowCategories = $q_get->fetch())
{
if ($currentParent != $rowCategories['pid'])
{
echo '<h1>'.htmlentities($rowCategories['parent_name']).'</h1>';
$currentParent = $rowCategories['pid'];
}

echo '<p>' . htmlentities($rowCategories['category_name']) . '</p>';

}
```

Above code will output it like as

```
<h1>Parent Cat 1</h1>
    <p>subcategory 1</p>
    <p>subcategory 2</p>
<h1>Parent cat 2</h1>
    <p> subcategory 3</p>
```

**Edit** @eggyal's comments there are some corrections to the answer

Comment: A few observations.  (1) beware to sort the resultset by parent category; (2) beware that different `parent_categories` might have the same `parent_name`, so you should really track/compare the `pid` instead; (3) beware that the value you're tracking might evaluate to `false`, so the initial parent value might not be output; (4) beware to escape output for HTML.

Comment: @eggyal i got your points the 1 and 2 really means thanks for the correction