# How to join tables and show respectively in tr in td in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have Two table in database one is employer and another is skill table. Skill table has all skills like type, language, and rate column and employer table has user contact fields. I want desire output which is in below image. the employ_id in skill table and id in employer table is foreign key relations.

[image: I want desire output which is shown in this image]

Comment: Don't use a mysql join. Instead query the employees, Then loop through employees in php  and pull each of their skill sets. Otherwise you will have lots of duplicate data being returned from the database.

Comment: How can I loop tr in td with 3 diffrent td and every td may have 2 or more tr?
can you please explain code little bit?

Comment: I am sure this would help you achieve the required output using single join query [Query for post and tags in same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766576/query-for-post-and-tags-in-same-query/31824955#31824955) , If you follow danielson317's comment you will have to face [**N+1 problem**](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/)

Comment: Another solution following tr td structure [SQL statement to display in group of certain column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007439/sql-statement-to-display-in-group-of-certain-column/24007621#24007621) and there are many more on stack you just need to apply right filter on questions