# select from 2 tables in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `article` and `image`.

In order to extract all articles of a particular user, I need to:

- query all the articles

  `SELECT * FROM article WHERE userid=100;`
- then loop through these articles, and extract their images with:

  `SELECT * FROM image WHERE articleid = currentArticleId;`

How can I achieve the same thing with just a single query?

Comment: You don't "loop" in SQL, you join the two tables over the `articleid` columns

Comment: google for subquery in sql

Comment: Use join , you can search for join in google

Comment: You can implement your logic as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171673/php-category-sub-category-tree

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a join or a subquery.

---

[Subquery:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

The subquery (The second query contained in brackets) will be executed and the ID(s) that are returned will be used to identify which rows from the initial query to grab. So if you imagine the subquery returns (1, 2, 3), the initial query will be looking for rows `WHERE articleid` is `IN` that list.

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE articleid IN (SELECT id FROM article WHERE userid=100);
```

---

[Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

Here you are telling MySQL that the `articleid` in `image` is related to the `id` column in the `article` table. Then you can just pull columns from either table. This is a watered down explanation so I recommend you read the link. There are various types of `JOIN` that will result in different results, so you should read about `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `OUTER` and `INNER` joins to make sure the resultset fits your needs. In this case, `JOIN` is equivalent to an `INNER` join.

```
SELECT
    image.col1,
    image.col2,
    image.colX,
    article.col1,
    article.col2,
    article.colX
FROM image
JOIN article ON article.id = image.articleid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I still got a small issue, that the result set doesn't match my example. Each image row now contains the  selected aticle columns. How can I group those images by each article?

Comment: Add `GROUP BY columnName` to the end of the query: [Reading](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: @Doctus I mean that I want to group those images then extract the result by articleid. I think `GROUP BY` can not help me in this case. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about select statements, joins, etc. here:
[MySQL Reference - Select Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM image
JOIN article ON article.id = image.articleid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE articleid  
 in(SELECT articleid   FROM article WHERE userid=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Doctus 's answer, but when joining the table you need to take care of  proper joining

1. Inner Join (the default Join) : when the coresponding records
   present in both the table in participation
2. Outer Join (Can be
       Left, RIGHT, or FULL) : when One or Both table dont have some
       matching records

.

In your case, some user might not have images.

```
--//This will also get the articles without any images
SELECT article.* , image.*
FROM article 
LEFT OUTER JOIN image
ON article.articleid  = image.articleid 
WHERE userid=100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE articleid IN (SELECT id FROM article WHERE userid=100; );
```

Hope this will help you.